# Testing styled components that show/hide on click only on mobile

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I have a component that looks like:

```js
import React, { ReactElement, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const ExpandedView = styled.div`
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: ${({ isExpanded }) => (isExpanded ? 'block' : 'none')};
  }
`

const Card () => {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setExpanded(!isExpanded)} data-test="card-button">Open</button>
      <ExpandedView isExpanded={isExpanded} data-test="expanded-view">
        Expanded view content
      </ExpandedView>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would love to have my tests setup below, but apparently you can't test nested components and only the parent component using `toHaveStyleRule`. Since this styling is ONLY on mobile, I can't do some condition in the react component. What I am being forced to do is create a separate component solely to test. I was hoping there was a better way to do this.

```js
describe('Card', () => {
  it('changes display', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Card />)
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="expanded-view]')).toHaveStyleRule(
      'display',
      'none',
      {
        media: '(max-width: 768px)'
      }
    )
    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="card-button"]')
      .first()
      .childAt(0)
      .simulate('click')
    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="expanded-view]')).toHaveStyleRule(
        'display',
        'block',
        {
          media: '(max-width: 768px)'
        }
      )
  })
})
```

Comment: One of the many reasons I've moved away from styled-components was the [inability to test my styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/338) and not getting much help/response. If you're not heavily invested, I'd recommend switching to [@emotion/styled](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emotion/styled). Exact same API, but much better support. Also supports [jest testing with CSS selectors](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/main/packages/jest#tohavestylerule)!